# How do you change the height of a NoteField box in a Sharepoint masterpage?

Tags: asp.net, sharepoint, master-pages, sharepoint-designer

I know you can change the width of a NoteField box using DisplaySize, but how do you modify the height so there are only a few rows in SharePoint Designer 2013?

Thanks!